# How to noindex in Google one page of a web site

Tags: noindex

I am interested how to prevent one page of a website to not get indexed by Google, or any other robots.
In my script i have the template with TPL files , Index.tpl , Header.tpl ....
So how do i tell google not to index page : login.tpl

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific URL (or a directory) no not be indexes by crawlers, a simple solution is to use a `robots.txt` file -- which will allow you to specify what can, and cannot, be indexed.

For more informations, see [**About /robots.txt**](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

For example, if you want a crawler not to index the `/my-page.php` URL, you could use something like this in your `robots.txt` file :

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /my-page.php
```

As a sidenote : files that should not be visible from end-users *(like include files, libraries, non-interpreted templates, ...)* should not be served by your webserver : no-one should be available to access those.

If using Apache, using a `.htaccess` file in a given folder *(provided this feature is enabled)*, you can prevent Apache from serving any file from that folder :

```
Deny from All
```

Note : nothing will be served by Apache from the directory that contains a `.htaccess` file with that content !

Comment: Cool,So i need to use .htaccess , But the problem is i need to exclude just files from the folder , not the entire folder .

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct. The robots.txt does not tell crawlers what to index and what not to index. That's what you use the meta-robots tag for. Have it serve noindex and you're good. 
See for example and further reading: http://yoast.com/x-robots-tag-play/

Answer (score 0):

I know i am late for the answers but this could help others also 
below is the more precise answer that you will see.

I am considering that you are using wordpress for your site.

You can use wordpress "CUSTOM FIELD" option.(you can find details [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields))

The first thing you need to do is add the following code to the head section of your theme’s header.php template.

And copy the below code

```
<?php
    $noindex = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'noindex-page', true);

    if ($noindex) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />';
    }
?>
```

Now all you need to do is specify a custom field entitled noindex-page and assign a value to it. It doesn’t matter what you enter. All you need to do is ensure that something is entered in the field so that the custom field noindex-page returns as true in the code you specified in your header.

please keep this in mind, this will also work for posts